# VS Code-Power Shell Command Line-crazy highlights

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

Environment:

- Windows Server 2019
- VSCode 1.59.1
- PowerShell 7.1.4 (same with PS 5.1)

Steps:

- Uninstall PS 7, VS Code, reinstall.
- $Profile files are all empty.
- settings.json is empty.

Typing one character on terminal command line is ok (plain character on terminal background). Typing a second or more characters gets this strange highlight (background turns magenta, same character color). I have the same setup across 4 computers and they are ok, just this one on the Server has this problem. The weird color highlighting makes it very hard to read!

[image]

Comment: With command prompt: `$PROFILE` do you get anything?

Comment: File name, but the file is empty.  Also settings.json is empty. There should be nothing that gives the color to the input line.

Answer (score 0):

Started fresh in another Windows 2019 server.
There was no problem in VS Code until using this PowerShell color tool caused the problem:
"concfg-COLOR Tool" import xxxxxx.json WHERE this line occurs:
"screen_colors": "dark_yellow,dark_magenta",
Changing the dark_magenta to dark_blue definitely changes the VS Code Terminal background
but changing to the screen backgound color we actually used #012456 did not work!!
So finally I just left it alone.

Then for VS Code, in Settings.json, changing "ansiMagenta" to the background color we use:
// "terminal.ansiMagenta": "#d338d3",
"terminal.ansiMagenta": "#012456",
did work. BUT WHY? if the settings.json were cleared out and I still had the problem.?
What is the relationship between "terminal.ansiMagenta" and the "dark_magenta" from the "concfg-COLOR Tool"?

So many strange mysteries but at least its working now!!